# How to remove duplicates in one of two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

So I have two arrays looking like this :

arr 1 :

```
[[Tue Feb 20 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, xxx, cc0902be495c4350a6bfcd1734c843b9, xxx, affiliate, 101723.0, ru, 9e09ee193e21766b1946e485eec9adcf, 0.81, 0.72, 6.05, 0.5265, 0.1053, 0.6318, 3.9325, 0.7865, 4.719, 0.468, 0.0936, 0.5616], [Tue Feb 21 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, xxx, f8875453e5354d88931e3474021f723a, xxx, affiliate, 101723.0, ru, b4cb6e13bc1909b6f04f8cd44b1374d5, 0.5, 0.44, 3.72, 0.325, 0.065, 0.39, 2.418, 0.4836, 2.9016, 0.286, 0.0572, 0.3432],[Tue Feb 22 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, xxx, f8875453e5354d88931e3474021f723a, xxx, affiliate, 101723.0, ru, b4cb6e13bc1909b6f04f8cd44b1374d5, 0.5, 0.44, 3.72, 0.325, 0.065, 0.39, 2.418, 0.4836, 2.9016, 0.286, 0.0572, 0.3432]]
```

arr 2 :

```
[[Tue Feb 20 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, xxx, cc0902be495c4350a6bfcd1734c843b9, xxx, affiliate, 101723.0, ru, 9e09ee193e21766b1946e485eec9adcf, 0.81, 0.72, 6.05, 0.5265, 0.1053, 0.6318, 3.9325, 0.7865, 4.719, 0.468, 0.0936, 0.5616], [Tue Feb 21 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, xxx, f8875453e5354d88931e3474021f723a, xxx, affiliate, 101723.0, ru, b4cb6e13bc1909b6f04f8cd44b1374d5, 0.5, 0.44, 3.72, 0.325, 0.065, 0.39, 2.418, 0.4836, 2.9016, 0.286, 0.0572, 0.3432],[Tue Feb 22 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, xxx, f8875453e5354d88931e3474021f723a, xxx, affiliate, 101723.0, ru, b4cb6e13bc1909b6f04f8cd44b1374d5, 0.5, 0.44, 3.72, 0.325, 0.065, 0.39, 2.418, 0.4836, 2.9016, 0.286, 0.0572, 0.3432],[Tue Feb 23 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018, xxx, f8875453e5354d88931e3474021f723a, xxx, affiliate, 101723.0, ru, b4cb6e13bc1909b6f04f8cd44b1374d5, 0.5, 0.44, 3.72, 0.325, 0.065, 0.39, 2.418, 0.4836, 2.9016, 0.286, 0.0572, 0.3432]]
```

What I want to achieve, but don't really know how, is to remove the entries in **arr 1** that have the same dates as those in **arr 2**. Sp, considering the data presented above, all entries in arr will need to be removed, because their dates overlap with the entrie's dates in **arr 2**.

How can I do this? The entry number or other values shouldn't matter. If, e.g, in **arr 1** I have 10k entries with date 5th of march and in **arr 2** I have one single entry with the same date, I still want these 10k entries in **arr 1** removed.

I tried to do this with filters, but since it's a **2d** array I don't think this was the correct approach at all.

Comment: you perform check based on date only ?? or other fields also ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` and `filter`.

Create a array of all dates in `arr2`

```
var allArr2Dates = arr2.map( s => s[0] );
```

And then filter `arr1` using this array

```
arr1 = arr1.filter( s => allArr2Dates.includes( s[0] ) );
```

**ES5 equivalent**

```
var allArr2Dates = arr2.map( function(s){ return s[0]; } );
arr1 = arr1.filter( function(s) { return allArr2Dates.includes( s[0] ); } );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Actually i forgot to mention that I was doing it under ECMASCRIPT 5. Would you mind writing the EC5 version as well?

Comment: thanks for the edit! i am getting this error : TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object Tue Feb 20 2018 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)  Do you know why is that?

Comment: Use `indexOf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, mixed filter and every.

```js
let one = [[1, 'aaa'], [2, 'bbb'], [3, '444']];

let second = [[14, 'aaa'], [2, 'bbb'], [6, 'ccc']];

const result = one.filter(data => second.every(dataAux => dataAux[0] !== data[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can be leveraged to overwrite related `elements` in `key` based `Arrays`.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const array1 = [['Tue Feb 20 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018', 'A1'], ['Tue Feb 21 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018', 'A1'],['Tue Feb 22 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018', 'A1']]
const array2 = [['Tue Feb 20 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018', 'A2'], ['Tue Feb 21 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018', 'A2'],['Tue Feb 22 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018', 'A2'],['Tue Feb 23 09:00:00 GMT+01:00 2018', 'A2']]

// Output.
const output = [...new Map([...array1, ...array2].map(day => [day[0], day])).values()]

// Log.
console.log(output)
```